# How to create drag attribute directive in angular 2.0?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

I am following [angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html) for creating attribute directive for drag but `ondrag` event is not working.On the other end  `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are working fine (mentioned in doc). Any suggestions ?

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input} from 'angular2/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[myHighlight]',
    host: {
        '(ondrag)' : 'onDrag()'
    }
})
export class HighlightDirective {
      //constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }
    onDrag(){
        console.log("onDrag...");
    }
}
```

Comment: See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LD5FJaI4OOFbKfvhjD4e?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `ondrag` event. The event you're looking for is just `drag`

Comment: got it. Stupid me.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to extend answer with more precise way.

`dragstart` & `dragstop` would be the correct event have handle on it, Where on `dragstart` add some class to element & on `dragstop` removed that class from element.